# Neo4jTemplate save not saving Java 8 LocalDateTime field

Tags: spring, spring-data-neo4j, jsr310

I am using spring-boot with spring-data-neo4j-rest. Maven dependencies are as

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My model has a field of type LocalDateTime

```
@NodeEntity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyModel {

@GraphId
private Long id;

private LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.now();   
private Date date = new Date();
...getter/setter
}
```

In service class this model is saved with Neo4jTemplate save method.

```
@Autowired
Neo4jTemplate template; 

public T create(T t) {
    T t1 = template.save(t);
    return t1;
}
```

The issue is while Date field is stored in Neo4j as timestamp, LocalDateTime is not stored at all. Not getting what am I doing wrong here. 
Is this required to add custom converter for LocalDateTime to long conversion and register as mentioned in [LocalDateTime is not converted to String but to Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866577/localdatetime-is-not-converted-to-string-but-to-json-object)